# Converting to a multi-project build

Tags: sbt, sbt-web

I am trying to convert from an sbt single project to an sbt multiproject.

I copied my `src` folder to a new directory `website` which I would like to use as a subproject. This changed the old (working)

```
lazy val website = (project in file("."))
.enablePlugins(SbtTwirl)
.enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
```

to

```
lazy val website = (project in file("website"))
.enablePlugins(SbtTwirl)
.enablePlugins(SbtWeb)
```

The part

```
Revolver.reStart <<= Revolver.reStart.dependsOn(WebKeys.assets in Assets)

(managedClasspath in Runtime) += (packageBin in Assets).value
```

stops working now though. The first one gives me

> [error] Reference to undefined setting:
>
> [error]
>
> [error]   fg2/web-assets:assets from fg2/*:reStart

and the second one

> [error] Reference to undefined setting:
>
> [error]
>
> [error]   fg2/web-assets:packageBin from fg2/runtime:managedClasspath